What is the difference between isAssignableFrom and instanceof in this example?
Taking the code below into consideration:
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Resource
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private HttpHeaders headers(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return headers;
    }

    private ResponseError responseError(String message,HttpStatus statusCode){
        ResponseError responseError = new ResponseError();
        responseError.setStatus("error");
        responseError.setError(message);
        responseError.setStatusCode(statusCode.value());
        return responseError;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleGeneral(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndeclaredThrowableException.class)) {
            UndeclaredThrowableException exception = (UndeclaredThrowableException) e;
            return handleBusinessException((BusinessException) exception.getUndeclaredThrowable(), request);
        } else {
            String message = messageSource.getMessage("error.server", new Object[]{e.getMessage()}, null);
            ResponseError error = responseError(message,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return handleExceptionInternal(e, error, headers(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({BusinessException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleBusinessException(BusinessException e, WebRequest request) {
        ResponseError error = responseError(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        return handleExceptionInternal(e, error, headers(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}

What would be the biggest difference between replacing
if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndeclaredThrowableException.class)) {

with
if (e instanceof UndeclaredThrowableException) {

Line 19.
I found some explanations but none detailed enough. I wanted to understand the situations in which I should use isAssignableFrom or instanceof.

At the very least, they will be have differently when e is null.

Java: class.isInstance() vs. class.isAssignableFrom() This link partially responds. I understand the difference between the concepts "instanceof" and "isAssignableFrom". My question is more in the practice of this code that I brought. I found some tutorials that specifically used isAssignableFrom to check the Exception.class within a GlobalExceptionHandler. I'm sorry if the title was too generic.

e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Whatever.class)

tests whether the runtime class of e is a superclass of Whatever,
e instanceof Whatever

tests whether the runtime class of e is a subclass of Whatever.
In your code, the latter makes more sense, but in modern Java, there is an even shorter and clearer way of writing that:
if (e instanceof Whatever w) {
    // w is now a variable of type Whatever
}


So isAssignableFrom is an older way of checking the instance of a class? Is it currently better to use instanceof?

@cator No. As mentioned, it's the difference between checking if e is a supertype versus checking if e is a subtype. The two test opposite things. As for the pattern matching at the end of the answer, that is a newer way to do instanceof, not isAssignableFrom, and does not change the semantics of the code. It requires Java 16+.


isAssignableFrom: This method checks if the class represented by one Class object is the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class represented by another Class object. It is used to determine if one class is assignable from another class or interface.
instanceof: This operator checks if an object is an instance of a particular class or interface, including instances of subclasses. It is used to test if an object is of a particular type.

